# Web Application Architecture and Web APIs

Tags: api, web-services, web-applications

In the Web Application Architecture, which layer is respsonsible for dealing or communicating with APIs? Is it the Application Layer? Or is it the Data Access Layer (using the service agents)?
Also, what kind of services do the service agents in the Data Access Layer deal with

[image: Web Application Architecture Photo 1]
[image: Web Application Architecture Photo 2]

Comment: From your image I think both application and business layers are interchangeable!

Comment: Yes they are. Sorry if the question wasn't clear. Actually I am asking about the layer that is responsible for communicating with APIs? Is it the Application Layer or Data Layer?

Comment: I believe it's the business layer

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot :) So do you know what kind of services do service agents deal with?